# Should i use database in my website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to build `website` that will show all my files from directory root.
Every file has category and several properties.
The thing is that every few minutes new files are added and every few days few files deleted.
Of course i want to update my `List/Database` with all this changes.
Should i using `Database` or maybe only hold a list with my object (represent a file) and after Every change update this list ?

Comment: How do you determine file category and properties - can u give an example?

Comment: The category is based on the file name and the property is based on the category

Comment: Then indeed you do not need the DB, see @Habib answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need database. You can refresh your view based on your file structure. Keeping the directory structure / files hierarchy  in database would be redundant.

Comment: What do you mean file structure ?

Comment: @user1860934 -  "files from directory root"

Comment: BTW is it good idea to use FileSystemWatcher to watch files changes ?

Comment: FileSystemWatcher wouldn't be useful if you weren't using something like SignalR to update your UI in real time. But even then, I'm not so sure using FileSystemWatcher on the web is a good idea.

Comment: @user1860934, if you're going to cache the entire file structure, sure. But I think in your case, just read it when it needs displayed. The problem with caching it is that you'd have to handle both insertions and deletions; and you'd have to handle them in that recursive file structure. I could be done, but it's probably not worth it.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher will trigger an event when an item changes. Unless you need something to happen when a file is created or deleted you don't need a FileSystemWatcher. A FSW wouldn't really be relevant in a web site - if nobody's on the site, it's pointless to trigger events.

Comment: So what is the best option for me ?

Comment: @user1860934, just read the file structure on every post back and populate the server control how you wish. Pretty straight forward here I think.

Comment: @user1860934, on every request, get the file structure and display it to user, You can update the view periodically.

Comment: And if my root folder contain about ~50,000 - 100,000 files ?

Comment: @user1860934, 100,000 records would be useless on a single page, You can implement paging, or get updates files in past 30 minutes or something like that.